# Reading MNIST database in java very slow

Tags: java, runtime, mnist

I have made an MNIST reader before in c++ which was really fast, now I tried to recreate it in Java but reading the labels and images from the dataset takes about 10 seconds which is way too long. I don't know a lot about Java IO and so I don't know what I am doing that makes it so slow.

Here is my code

```
public static double[][] loadImages(File imageFile) {
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFile);

        //Skip Magic number
        inputStream.skip(4);

        //Read Image Number
        int imageNum = nextNByte(4);

        //Get Image dimensions
        int rows = nextNByte(4);
        int cols = nextNByte(4);

        //Initialize the image array
        double[][] images = new double[imageNum][rows*cols];

        //Place the input
        for(int i = 0; i<imageNum;i++){
            for(int k = 0; k<cols*rows;k++){
                images[i][k]= nextNByte(1);
            }
        }

        //Close Input Stream
        inputStream.close();

        //Verbose Output
        System.out.println("Images Loaded!");

        return images;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.getCause();
    }

    //Verbose Output
    System.out.println("Couldn't Load Images!");

    return null;
}
```

That is my images file and the labels one uses the same method so I will not put it up. Here is a utility function I made for this which reads a N amount of Bytes and returns it in an int.

```
private static int nextNByte(int n) throws IOException {
    int k=inputStream.read()<<((n-1)*8);
    for(int i =n-2;i>=0;i--){
        k+=inputStream.read()<<(i*8);
    }
    return k;
}
```

Any help on why this is so slow will help me. I have used someone else's example in which he used byte buffers and it worked fast(about a second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to use a `BufferedInputStream` like this:

```
inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile));
```

Without buffering each call `inputStream.read()` fetches a single byte from the OS.

Comment: Oh so basically I am asking the OS to get it for me 60k times or so and if i make it into a buffered input stream it all gets stored in ram for easy access?

Comment: @ItayBachar sort of - without a buffered input stream you ask to OS 60k times for a single byte. With buffered input stream the buffered input stream fetches a buffer full from the OS (8kbytes if I remember correctly), which would mean about 8 calls to the OS. The rest of the read calls read from the RAM buffer, which is substantially faster.